# Pure css parallax (perspective) not working on html element

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, parallax, perspective

Cannot make the perspective property on html element working. I would like to create a full page parallax scroll effect but it seems to work just on the body element what generates a lot of issue. If I use the body to scroll the page then (default behaviour: Chrome and Firefox put the vertical scrollbar on html element) window.onscroll events stop firing. If I try to put on html element then the parallax effect stop working.

Correction: This solution only works on chrome based browsers, I wrote the question because It seems not working on Firefox.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {console.log('onscroll')}
```

```css
    html {
      perspective: 1000px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    body {
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto;
      transform-style: preserve-3d
    }
    .section {
      position: relative;
      height: 100vh;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    .wrapper {
      transform-style: preserve-3d
    }

    .parallax::after {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateZ(-500px) scale(2);
      background-size: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    .static {
      background: red;
    }

    .bg1::after {
      background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/900/700');
    }

    .bg2::after {
      background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/800/600');
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="wrapper">
    <section class="section parallax bg1">
      <h1>placekitten</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section static">
      <h1>Static</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section parallax bg2">
      <h1>placekitten</h1>
    </section>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```